# SpringMVC Boolean Binding - Getter Named as "is" rather than "get"

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, model-binding

We're unable to bind a Boolean value in our SpringMVC form because our getter for that field is called

```
isData()
```

vs.

```
getData()
```

Error Message:

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'data' of bean class [Model]: Bean property 'data' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Is there a quick workaround for this?

Comment: Yes: adding the getter to the class.

Comment: We can't modify our domain objects. What are some other solutions? A custom Boolean property editor?